# Paypal getting error in php

Tags: php, paypal, kohana-3

I am using paypal in my local. It is not working now. I getting the PayPal API request for SetExpressCheckout failed:

> error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert
>   handshake failure(35)

error message.

```
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL            => $this->api_url(),
                CURLOPT_POST           => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => http_build_query($post, NULL, '&'),
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
```

can you advise me. how to resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

Your server software stack needs to be updated.

Take a look at this info about the [POODLE Vulnerability](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vunerability/).